# I have an assignment where I need to check whether I can partition a set into two subset that are equal in sum

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming, backtracking

I have an assignment where I need to check whether I can partition a set into two subsets that are equal in sum and output the subset as a result.
For example

```
[[[1,1,2,2,2,3,5,5,9]
```

gives you a result of

```
[[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5], [1, 5, 9]], [[1, 2, 2, 5, 5], [1, 2, 3, 9]],
[[1, 1, 3, 5, 5], [2, 2, 2, 9]], [[2, 3, 5, 5], [1, 1, 2, 2, 9]]]
```

Currently my output is the same but the order is different

```
[[[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5], [1, 5, 9]], [[2, 2, 2, 9], [1, 1, 3, 5, 5]],
 [[1, 2, 3, 9], [1, 2, 2, 5, 5]], [[2, 3, 5, 5], [1, 1, 2, 2, 9]]]
```

They say is possible to achieve the same order result but till now I still cannot get the same order

```
# Returns true if there exists a sublist of list `nums[0…n]` with the given total
def subsetSum(nums, n, total,secondSubset): 

    # return true if subsets are equal 
    if sum(nums) == sum(secondSubset):
        return (True,nums,secondSubset)

    # base case: no items left or sum becomes negative
    if n < 0 or total < 0:
        return (False,nums,secondSubset)

    # Number to include/exclude 
    numConsider = nums[n]

    # Case 1. Include the current item `nums[n]` in the subset and recur
    # for remaining items `n-1` with the remaining sum `total-nums[n]`
    
    # Remove it from first subset and adding it to the second 
    nums.remove(numConsider)
    secondSubset.append(numConsider)
    
    include,first,second = subsetSum(nums, n - 1, total - numConsider,secondSubset)

    # return true if we get subset by including the current item
    if include:
        return (True,nums,secondSubset)

    # Since number does not need to be included, revert back to the same subset 
    nums.append(numConsider)
    secondSubset.remove(numConsider)

    # Case 2. Exclude the current item `nums[n]` from the subset and recur for
    # remaining items `n-1`
    exclude,first,second = subsetSum(nums, n - 1, total,secondSubset)

    # return true if we get subset by excluding the current item
    return (exclude,nums,secondSubset)


# Returns true if given list `nums[0…n-1]` can be divided into two
# sublists with equal sum
def partition(nums):
    total = sum(nums)

    # check all the nums
    state,first,second = subsetSum(nums, len(nums) - 1, total/2,[])

    newTotal = sum(first)

    
    return state,first,second


def partitionSet(collection):
    if len(collection) == 1:
        yield [ collection ]
        return

    first = collection[0]
    for smaller in partitionSet(collection[1:]):
        # insert `first` in each of the subpartition's subsets
        for n, subset in enumerate(smaller):
            yield smaller[:n] + [[ first ] + subset]  + smaller[n+1:]
        # put `first` in its own subset 
        yield [ [ first ] ] + smaller


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Input: a set of items
    # nums = [7, 3, 1, 5.3, 4.5, 8.2]
    # nums = [7,3,1,5,4,8]

    nums = [ 1,1,2,2,2,3,5,5,9]
    # Get the state, first and second subset 
    # state,first,second = partition(nums)
    # if state:
    #   print('Set can be partitioned')
    #   print('The first subset : ' , first)
    #   print('The second subset : ' , second)
    # else:
    #   print('Set cannot be partitioned')

    # newTotal = sum(first)
    # totalNum = first+second

    newSet = []
    # Find all possible set of the input 
    for n, p in enumerate(partitionSet(nums), 1):
        # Only consider those with 2 partition
        if(len(p)==2):
            # Only consider if the total match 
            if(sum(p[0]) == sum(p[1])):
                # Sort the partition
                newP = [sorted(p[0]),sorted(p[1])]
                # Ensure new partition is new not added before
                if(newP not in newSet):
                    insertState = True
                    for j in newSet:
                        # Ensure new partition is not part of another enumeration 
                        if(newP[0]==j[1]):
                            insertState = False
                    if(insertState):
                        # print(newP)
                        newSet.append(newP)

    print(newSet)
```

Comment: Sets are unordered by definition. If there is a sorting criterion, your professor needs to share how the results should be sorted.

Comment: (Tangentially, code you put in `if __name__ == '__main__’:` should be trivial; the purpose of this boilerplate is to allow you to `import` the code, which you will not want to do anyway if the logic you need is not available via `import`. See also stackoverflow.com/a/69778466/874188)